# Image names with hash not working in html and php

Tags: php, html, image

I have to work on images whose name has # in it. I have noticed that if image name has #, eg: layer#1.png, then it is not opening in browser, neither it can be downloaded using  code.
If I try to get file name in php from url, $_GET can also not fetch full file name. I have to work on hundreds of files with name # in it, used for id. Please let me know of any possible solution available?

Comment: You probably need to urlencode the filename, since the `#` symbol means something in the path.

Comment: I would suggest, if possible, change `#` to some other character or remove it at all. It can lead to some issues, since `#` denotes hash part of URL

Comment: you can use URL encoding to replace special characters, including the hash symbol `$filename = 'layer#1.png';`  to `$encodedFilename = urlencode($filename);
`

Comment: File name is 'laye r#1.png'. If I do urlencode, it makes it 'laye+r%231.png'. HTML a href code fails to open image from path: "https://path/to/image/laye+r%231.png" and even if I try to download it, using a href download. It says file not available on site. I would like to download file in its original name 'laye r#1.png'.

Comment: What web server are you running? Apache? What do the server logs say? Is it truly a 404, or something else? Are you sure the `path/to/image` is correct based on your server's configuration? I don't believe "*file not available on site*" is a "standard" HTTP error thrown by a server; is there some sort of middleware or non-standard configuration at play?

Comment: Web server is LiteSpeed, used by Hostinger. In Server logs 404 Error say: 'GET /projects/dropbox-resize-images/imagine/images/created/laye+r%231.png HTTP/1.1' as the last log message. Path is correct. Simple image names are opening. Rest you can check online which server Hostinger shared hosting uses, for your reference.

Comment: I have made it work using $filename = str_replace(' ', '%20', $filename);
$filename = str_replace('#', '%23', $filename); however still on downloading image, it downloads image name as 'laye%20r%231.png' not 'laye r#1.png'

Comment: I have fixed the issue by using above code of str_replace for file path  and urldecode added for download = filename1 <a href="path/to/image'.$filename.'" download="'.$filename1.'"> Thanks for your efforts.